# Requirementes on rpmbuild

Tags: centos, redhat, rpm, epel

I'm building a RPM package and one of my requirements is python-pip, only available in Epel repositories. (following line),

```
Requires:       python python-pip python-devel
```

If the OS already has epel-release installed, then everything works fine.

But if it's not installed, then I get a broken dependencies error.

I want to find a way that my RPM installs epel-release before checking for requirements.

I've tried to put epel-release in the same line, but it didn't work.

Is there a way of doing this? Installing it before checking for dependencies?

Comment: It is not for you to install another repo. You should check that it is installed or not and then tell the administrator that it is required.

Answer (score 1):

A clean way to deal with this is checking if `epel-release` is installed in the %pre` section and aborting if it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I just put the epel dependency in the README file. But later I'll put it on the %pre section.